# accordion toggle is not working with api response in angular 7

Tags: angular

I'm using angular 7 and accordion is working fine with static data (means create an object in `ngOnInit()`)

After load getting, a response from API accordion is not working

**Note: Both static and response data are identical (same object)**

```
//this is code to toggle manually
 const accordions = document.querySelectorAll('[data-toggle="dds__collapse"]');
    accordions.forEach( accordion => {
      new Collapse(accordion, {});
    });
```

In this first time, it takes a double click on accordion then it works normally.

Comment: please add your code using response from api.

Comment: `this.feedbackService.getRetrieveDetails(data).subscribe((response:any) => {
      this.whatsNewData=response.whatsNewResponse;
    },`

Comment: I think you should call teh accordions code inside you modify your whatsNewData, I wonder your accordions are rendered base on your whatsNewData,

Comment: i tried but no luck. if put some static data to whatsNewData  it works fine. if change whatsData by response it won't work it take double click in first time then it work normally

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.